# How to automatically structure java class source code?

Tags: java, android-studio, class, organization, code-organization

I am looking for a way to quickly organize source code within java classes, preferably have the different sections such as fields, methods, etc. in alphabetical order and within their own section. I have googled around and can't find any tool that does anything close to this. Am I the only one who would like something like this?

I am using Android Studio.

Here is an example of what I mean by "organize source code".

Going from this:

```java
class ExampleClass{
    
    private String text;
    private boolean flag;
    
    public void method{
        int i = 2;
    }
    
    public int number;
    
    
    
    private boolean getFlag(){
        return this.flag;
    }
    
    private ExampleInnerInterface interface;
    
    interface ExampleInnerInterface{
        void fire();
    }
    
    private void setFlag(boolean flag){
        this.flag = flag;
    }
}
```

To this:

```
class ExampleClass {

  //  Fields
  public int number;

  private boolean flag;
  private ExampleInnerInterface interface;
  private String text;

  //  Getters
  private boolean getFlag() {
    return this.flag;
  }

  //  Setters
  private void setFlag(boolean flag) {
    this.flag = flag;
  }

  //  Methods
  public void method {
    int i = 2;
  }

  //  Inner classes
  interface ExampleInnerInterface {
    void fire();
  }
}
```

This type of organization makes it a lot easier for me to manage my code. I know that you can just search for what you want, so finding what you need isn't hard at all. I want this to be clean for when I do handovers, which would cause a scenario where the person would need to know what is searchable before they can search for it.

Any help would appreciated!

Comment: What IDE are you currently using?

Comment: I am using Android Studio. I looked for a plugin in android studio to do this, but alas, no luck there either

Comment: If I am not mistaken, you have built-in tool for intelligent code outline in Android Studio (also available in IntelliJ IDEA too). Unfortunately it doesn't organise alphabetically but outlines code structure pretty well.

Comment: *Am I the only one who would like something like this?* - Probably not the only one.  But I for one think that (re-)organizing the code like that is a bad idea.  (And if you don't care what I think ... don't ask rhetorical questions :-) )

Comment: I haven't come across a feature that would restructure code like this. There are other formatting tools that apply "beautify", but that isn't quite what I'm looking for. Could you maybe direct me to what you mean? I quick google didn't come up with anything.

Comment: To be honest, this sounds very much like a request to find / recommend a plugin for you to use.  That would be off-topic.

Comment: Any method would suffice. My research has come up null. If Android Studio itself can do it that would be cool too. If the functionality exists, I can't seem to find it.

Comment: Greater than the problem of "organizing" members within a class is organizing modules and packages within a project.  Having readable, maintainable code is important, but this question doesn't excite me with its importance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In AndroidStudio (and all modern variants of IntelliJ) go the *Code* menu -> *Reformat File...* and in the dialog make sure you check the options *Optimize Imports*, *Rearrange Code* and *Code Cleanup*. It does not sort methods alphabetically, but at least it

- sorts and weeds out your import statements
- puts all properties (fields) at the top
- removes all superfluous empty lines

The behavior can also be influenced by the languages code style in the IDEs perferences (at least the pure formatting stuff, like where to put spaces, parentheses and so on).

Comment: This really helped. Thanks!